# String Function - Padding the string

Tags: javascript, string, function

The leftPad function will make string be a certain length by padding it on the left. How do we make the leftPad function work as follows?

```
// If the input is empty, return an empty string
leftPad('') // ''

// When given just a string, it returns that string
leftPad('abc') // 'abc'

// When given a string and a number, it will pad the string with spaces
// until the string length matches that number. Notice that the code
// below does NOT add four spaces -- rather, it pads the string until
// the length is four
leftPad('abc', 4) // ' abc'

// If the padding given is less than the length of the initial string,
// it just returns the string
leftPad('abc', 2) // 'abc'

// If given a third argument that is a single character, it will pad
// the string with that character
leftPad('abc', 6, 'z') // 'zzzabc'
```

This is the current code I have for the first part of the problem - if the input is empty, returning an empty string:

```
function leftPad (string, padding, character) {
    let result = ""
    if (string.length === 0) {
        return result
    }

    if (string){

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can't ask questions related to homework.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Also, hint: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz You can definitely ask questions related to homework. You just can't ask broad questions that haven't had an attempt yet, regardless of whether or not they're related to homework.

Comment: Marc, please rephrase this so we know what the actual question is.

Comment: Rephrased. Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't answer the whole question as it seems to be a homework problem. But you can probably make good use of the built in string [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) function to build the `paddedString` on the left based on the `padding` parameter.

```js
function leftPad(string, padding, character) {
  let result = "", padCharacter = ' ';
  if (string.length === 0) {
    return result;
  }
  
  let paddedString = padCharacter.repeat(padding);
  console.log('Left padding will be "' + paddedString + '"');
  // return something
}

leftPad('hello', 5);
leftPad('world', 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution for left-padding or right padding with/without padding character (default is blank space).

Example:
     String MyNewString = rightPad(MyOldString, 12);
or
     String MyNewString = leftPad(MyOldString, 8, "0");

```
public static String leftPad(String string, int length) {
    return leftPad(string, length, " ");
}

public static String leftPad(String string, int length, String pad) {
    int L = string.length();
    if (L < length)
        return pad.repeat(length - string.length()) + string;
    else
        return string;
}

public static String rightPad(String string, int length) {
    return rightPad(string, length, " ");
}

public static String rightPad(String string, int length, String pad) {
    int L = string.length();
    if (L < length)
        return string + pad.repeat(length - string.length());
    else
        return string;
}
```